# Print the PDF from the excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an VBA macro, this macro will the print the pdf file. But now it prints through the default printer.
I need to choose the printer name and print dialog box must be opened from there i need to select the printer.

```
Sub GetBOM()

Dim strPth As String, strFile As String

strPth = "C:\"
strFile = "X.pdf"
 
If Not PrintPDF(0, strPth & strFile) Then
    MsgBox "Printing failed"
End If
End Sub

Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
    ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
 
Public Function PrintPDF(xlHwnd As Long, FileName As String) As Boolean
Dim X As Long

On Error Resume Next
X = ShellExecute(xlHwnd, "Print", FileName, 0&, 0&, 3)

If Err.Number > 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    PrintPDF = False
Else
    PrintPDF = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility to use this printing method in a way to involve a print dialog window. It uses the default printer. But the next way will allow you to previously set the default printer, from the installed ones.

Please, copy the next code in a standard module:

```
Sub SetDefaultPrinter_()
  Dim RegObj As Object, prDevices, arrPr, strRegValue As String
  Dim i As Long, strPrint As String, printNo As Variant
  Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
  
  Set RegObj = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
  RegObj.enumvalues HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices", prDevices, arrPr
    
    strPrint = "Please write the number (between zero and " & UBound(prDevices) & ")" & _
                     "  in front of the printer name to be set as Default:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    For i = 0 To UBound(prDevices)
        strPrint = strPrint & i & " - " & prDevices(i) & vbCrLf
    Next
    
    strPrint = strPrint & vbCrLf & "NOTE: You need to press ""Yes"" in User Account Control to allow the change!"
    printNo = InputBox(strPrint, "Set Default printer")
    
    If IsNumeric(printNo) Then
        If printNo > 0 And printNo <= UBound(prDevices) Then
           Debug.Print IsDefaultPrinter(CStr(prDevices(printNo))): Stop
            If Not IsDefaultPrinter(CStr(prDevices(printNo))) Then
                SetDefaultPrint prDevices(printNo)
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "You must enter a number between zero and " & UBound(prDevices) & "!", vbInformation, "Wrong number..."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "You must enter a NUMERIC value (the number before the chosen printer)...", vbInformation, _
                       "Wrong input..."
    End If
End Sub

Sub SetDefaultPrint(ByVal prName As String)  'It works...
   CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "cmd.exe", _
             "/c wmic printer where name='" & prName & "' call setdefaultprinter", , "runas", 1
   '/c = close cmd window
   '/k = keep cmd window
End Sub

Function IsDefaultPrinter(printerName As String) As Boolean
    Dim computer As String, wmiService As Object, installedPrinters  As Variant, printer As Object
 
    computer = "."
 
    'Get the WMI object
    Set wmiService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & computer & "\root\cimv2")
 
    'Retrieve information about the installed printers (by running a query).
    Set installedPrinters = wmiService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
 
    For Each printer In installedPrinters 'loop between the installed printers:
        If UCase(printer.name) = UCase(printerName) And printer.Default = True Then
            IsDefaultPrinter = True: Exit Function
        End If
    Next printer
End Function
```

You need to insert a single code line in your existing sub:

```
Sub GetBOM()
 Dim strPth As String, strFile As String

 strPth = "C:\"
 strFile = "X.pdf"
 
 SetDefaultPrinter_ 'set the default printer

 If Not PrintPDF(0, strPth & strFile) Then
    MsgBox "Printing failed"
 End If
End Sub
```

If you know the printer name to be set as default you should use a single `Sub` (`SetDefaultPrint`) and a single call:

```
   SetDefaultPrint "MyPrinterName"
```

It works in Windows 10/11, too...